# Convert varchar to nvarchar

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2000

My company use sql server 2000 to store data . There is a table with a column named 'Vattu' .
The problem is that : this column declare as varchar data type , however it's save both unicode and anscii value !

So every time I show this column data on web , it show unreadable characters.
Is there any way to convert data to unicode value using c# ?

Comment: Why not alter the column to nvarchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search would have given you the answer. Anyway you use System.Text.Encoding to encode the ascii to unicode. check the sample code at [Encoding.Convert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.encoding.convert%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Also converting the column datatype to NVarchar will be better in long run. Doing so you will save CPU processing that you will be using due to conversion at c# level.

Comment: Tks for your help . Actually change column datatype is the best  solution ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the data type of the column to `nvarchar` in order to store Unicode data.

The Unicode data you've already tried to store in the column is gone - you can't magically get it back, unless your application logged the data or you were running traces of all commands and still have access to those.